# Don't show the formula in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following formula which works well for me, but I don't want the complete formula to be shown. I just want the *result* to be shown. How can I do it?

This is my code which works fine:

```
Dim LastR As Integer

With Worksheets("DashBoard")
    LastR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("D9").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(StoreData!$A$2:$A$10000=$E$3,IF(YEAR(StoreData!$C$2:$C$10000)=C9,StoreData!$B$2:$B$10000)))"
    .Range("D9").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("D9:D" & LastR)
End With
```

I made this other code so that it only shows the result of the formula, but when I run it, all cells have the same value.

```
Dim Hjs As Worksheet
Set Hjs = ActiveSheet

With Hjs.Range("D9:D" & Hjs.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    .FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(StoreData!$A$2:$A$10000=$E$3,IF(YEAR(StoreData!$C$2:$C$10000)=C9,StoreData!$B$2:$B$10000)))"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

I only want the result of the formula to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AutoFill an Array Formula (VBA)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFillArrayFormula()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim sLast As Long
    With wb.Worksheets("StoreData")
        sLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    Dim dLast As Long
    Dim dFormula As String
    
    With wb.Worksheets("DashBoard")
        dLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        dFormula = "=SUM(IF(StoreData!A$2:A$" & sLast _
            & "=$E$3,IF(YEAR(StoreData!C$2:C$" & sLast _
            & ")=C9,StoreData!B$2:B$" & sLast & ")))"
        With .Range("D9:D" & dLast)
            .Cells(1).FormulaArray = dFormula
            .Cells(1).AutoFill Destination:=.Offset
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: {VBasic2008} --- Excellent solution, thanks for the support And thanks for adding an additional solution to what I was looking for, and in this case it becomes very useful in my code.

Comment: The syntax near "`.Cells(1).AutoFill Destination:=.Offset`" looks strange. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: `.Offset` (`.Offset(0, 0)`)  is a way to reference `wb.Worksheets("DashBoard").Range("D9:D" & dLast)`. Something like `Range("A1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A10")`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Use `R1C1` reference style rather than `A1` reference style when setting an array formula. Makes your life easier.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Hjs As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    Set Hjs = ActiveSheet
    
    With Hjs
        lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        With .Range("D9:D" & lRow)
            .Formula = "=SUM(IF(StoreData!$A$2:$A$10000=$E$3,IF(YEAR(StoreData!$C$2:$C$10000)=C9,StoreData!$B$2:$B$10000)))"
            .FormulaArray = .FormulaR1C1
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great stuff `.FormulaArray = .FormulaR1C1`. Had no idea.